# Associating _existing_ objects with a User through has_one and belongs_to?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, belongs-to, has-one

So here are my models:

user.rb:
`has_one :interview_slot`

interview_slot.rb: `belongs_to :user`

An `interview_slot` has a `start_time`, an `end_time`, and a `available` boolean.

Say, for instance, that I have already generated a list of 20 `interview_slot` instances, and all I want to do is let my users choose 1 of them from a dropdown box.

I first check whether a user already has an interview slot:

```
@interview_slot = find_interview_slot(@rushee)

  def find_interview_slot(user)
    return InterviewSlot.find_by(user_id: user.id)
  rescue
    nil
  end
```

If `@interview_slot` is `nil`, then I want to display a list of all of the interview slots that are still `available` in a dropdown box, and I want the user to be able to select one of the interview slots, hit submit, and have the specified `InterviewSlot` be associated to the User. My question is, how do I write the form that will do this? I'm only familiar with calling something like `@user.interview_slots.build` and calling `form_for` like: `form_for(@interview_slot) do |f|`, but obviously I don't want to build a new interview_slot in this situation, I just want to associate existing interview_slots with users.

Any insight? Thanks.

EDIT: I also have an instance variable that is a collection of all InterviewSlots that are not yet associated with a user: `@available_slots = InterviewSlot.where(user_id: nil)`; I just don't know how to make the form that lets a user choose a single slot from this collection and associates the slot with the user.

EDIT 2:

I have this code right now:

```
    <%= form_for(@interview_slot) do |f| %>

      <% slots_for_select = {}
        @available_slots.each do |slot|
          slots_for_select[slot.start_time.strftime("%a. %D | %l:%M %p")] = slot
        end %>

      <%= select_tag(:interview_slot, options_for_select(slots_for_select)) %>

      <%= f.submit "Schedule Interview", class: "btn btn-sm" %>

    <% end %>
```

This gives me a dropdown box of all available interview slots, but the problem is, once again, that `@interview_slot` is set equal to `@user.interview_slots.build(interview_slot_params)` in the controller -- how do I make it just update the selected `interview_slot` with the `@user`'s id instead of creating a new interview_slot?

Answer (score 0):

```
# interview_slots_controller.rb

def update
  interview_slot = InterviewSlot.find(params[:interview_slot_id])
  interview_slot.user_id = your_current_user.id
  interview_slot.save
end
```